# How can I fix this method that convert Number in String to show the correct number of decimal digits?

Tags: java, decimal, bigdecimal

I have the following problem.

I am using this method to convert a Number (as a BigDecimal) to a formatted string:

```
/**
 * @param n il Number da formattare
 * @param thou_sep separator for hundreds
 * @param dec_sep  separator for decimal digits
 * @param number of decimal digits to show
 * @return a string representing the number
 * @author Andrea Nobili
 */
public static String getFormattedNumber(Number n, String thou_sep, String dec_sep, Integer decimalDigits) {

    if (n == null) return "";

    double value = n.doubleValue();

    if (decimalDigits != null && decimalDigits < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("[" + decimalDigits + " < 0]");

    DecimalFormatSymbols s = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    if (thou_sep != null && thou_sep.length() > 0) {
        s.setGroupingSeparator(thou_sep.charAt(0));
    }
    if (dec_sep != null && dec_sep.length() > 0) {
        s.setDecimalSeparator(dec_sep.charAt(0));
    }
    DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat();
    f.setDecimalFormatSymbols(s);
    if (thou_sep == null || thou_sep.length() == 0) {
        f.setGroupingUsed(false);
    }
    if (decimalDigits != null) {
        f.setMaximumFractionDigits(decimalDigits);
    }
    f.setMaximumIntegerDigits(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    String formattedNumber = f.format(value);
    return ("-0".equals(formattedNumber)) ? "0" : formattedNumber;
}
```

For example if I call something like:

```
utilityClass.getFormattedNumber(57.4567, null, ",", 2)
```

I obtain the string **57,45**

Ok, this work fine.

My problem is that if I try to perform it with a number having not decimal digits (for example passing the value **57** it return the String **57**. I want that in this case it return the string **57.00** (because I have specified that I want 2 decimal digits in the input parameter of this method)

How can I fix this issue and obtain the correct number of decimal digits?

Comment: Is this for a school project?  If not, stop wasting your time and use a `NumberFormat`. If it is, let us know and we can try to guide you in fixing your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DecimalFormat setMinimumFractionDigits and set it to the same as the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the minimum fraction digits along with maximum fraction digits.

```
f.setMaximumFractionDigits(decimalDigits);
f.setMinimumFractionDigits(decimalDigits);
```

[Java Doc for DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setMinimumFractionDigits(int))

Answer (score 0):

For DecimalFormat you can use the constructor that requires a pattern. In your patterns a `#` symbol represents a zero or blank if the zero doesn't need to be printed, like after a decimal. If you want the zero to be printed then you replace the `#` with a `0`. For example:

```
#,###,###.##
```

Will only show a zero if it is require like 0.54 or 0.3 but not in whole numbers.

```
#,###,###.00
```

will show the trailing zeros up to 2 decimal places like 2.50 or 79.00.

Comment: mmm and how can I do to set this settings for my method?

Comment: Since you are already receiving the number of decimal digits as a number then the answer Aestel gave is more appropriate.